# Change comment in terms of if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, comments

In Excel :

A1 = drop-down list of the 3rd days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed)

B1 = IF(A1="Mon"; "Monday"; IF(A1="Tue"; "Tuesday"; IF(A1="Wed"; "Wednesday"; "Error")))

I would like to change comment in terms on B1 :

If B1 = "Monday", I would like a comment on B1 with "Monday is the first day of a week in many countries".

If B1 = "Tuesday", I would like a comment on B1 with "Tuesday is the second day of a week in many countries".

If B1 = "Wednesday", I would like a comment on B1 with "Wednesday is the children day in many countries".

Is it possible without VBA ??
Is it possible with VBA ??

Comment: I don't think it's possible without VBA to have dynamic comments. That said it is easy with VBA using a Worksheet_Change event, checking that the cell changed is in column A, adding comment to desired cell if it doesn't exist and then setting its text and visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the worksheet event macro that Mark Balhoff described:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = r.Value
    If v = "Mon" Then msg = "Monday is the first day of a week in many countries"
    If v = "Tue" Then msg = "Monday is the first day of a week in many countries"
    If v = "Wed" Then msg = "Wednesday is the children day in many countries"
    With Range("B1")
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = True
        .Comment.Text Text:=msg
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: +1 for taking the time I didn't have to write all that detail out. Only things I would note: 1) What does the OP want to happen if it doesn't match any of those valid values? (B1 = "Error") Current logic should end up with an empty comment. 2) If the OP is applying the same logic throughout column A / B (he doesn't explicitly say), then three lines have to change.